# Exchange journaling folder structure

Tags: php, email, synchronization, exchange-server-2010

I'm indexing and storing the journalled e-mails from several exchange accounts. But I would like to be able to also have the exchange directory structures synced (on like 1 time a day).

I do have access to install something / create a local solution on the exchange server. Maybe someone could give me some pointers.

Comment: I think you have to specify what you really need. It seems like you are asking simply how to backup some folders. What is so special here?

Comment: Well I'm looking for a solution which allow me to get the folderstructure in my application (where I receive the journaled emails). Is anything like EWS a solution? It needs to be as lightweight / fast as possible ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try Backup using the EWS (Exchange Web Service). (see http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO73792 )

or [Backup Exchange Server 2010 With Windows Server Backup](http://www.wikihow.com/Back-Up-Microsoft-Exchange-Server#How_to_Backup_Exchange_Server_2010_With_Windows_Server_Backup)

Additionally to be safe you should backup the filesystem folders incrementally with a tool like [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/howto/)

Comment: I'm kind of more looking for a way to just export an array of like the folders (which would contain an array of uniquemessageID's per folder).